# Haskell IntList to String

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use operations like square on a list of Int and afterwards give the initial value and the result out in a string. For example:

IntListToString square [5,6,7] should result in something like 5=25 6=36 =7=49

My guess is the declaration has to look like this

```
IntListToString :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> String
```

Im struggling with the function itself. Do I have to use the map-function and afterwards convert into the right format?

What would your suggestions on solving this be?

Comment: `f g = unwords . map (\x-> show x ++ "=" ++ show (g x))`  should work.
For f (^2) [5,6,7] i get result "5=25 6=36 7=49"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try

```
showBeforeAfter before after = show before ++ "=" ++ show after
transformBeforeAfter f x = showBeforeAfter x (f x)
mapBeforeAfter f = map (transformBeforeAfter f)
beforeAfter f xs = unwords (mapBeforeAfter f xs)
```

where beforeAfter is an implementation of your IntListToString. Please note that function names must start with a symbol (excluding a colon) or a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works perfectly. Is there an easy way to implement new lines after each result?

Comment: Yes. Use unlines instead of unwords.